# What are the benefits and cost of doing push after each commit than push after many commits

Tags: git

I have developed a habit of pushing to the `origin` after each commit. Most of my commits are rather trivial, in the sense that I commit after making small changes. Is it a good practice?

I am under the impression that pushing after each small commit increases the size of repository compared to pushing after making several commits. Is this understanding wrong?

Comment: Something I recommend that you read: http://sandofsky.com/blog/git-workflow.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have developed a habit of pushing to the origin after each commit.
>   Most of my commits are rather trivial, in the sense that I commit
>   after making small changes. Is it a good practice?

In my opinion, you should not push every commit to the origin. Instead, use interactive rebasing when you finish working with a feature to squash the smaller commits, and push the feature as one commit to the origin. But there's not definite answer for this - googling for "git workflow" will give you several options.

> I am under the impression that pushing after each small commit
>   increases the size of repository compared to pushing after making
>   several commits. Is this understanding wrong?

Wrong. But if you rebase before pushing, then the squashed commits won't end up in the origin.

Answer (score 4):

As long as your commits reside only in your local repository you can fiddle with them (`git commit --amend` to fix last commit, or `git rebase -i` to reorder and tidy up your work). Pushing them right after commiting makes it rather hard to fix later.

I like to push my changes once a day, unless they are about to be deployed or tested by someone else. It gives me a margin to find out that I have commited something a bit too early.

It should not affect size of your repository in any way.

Comment: Also, you should have a good workspace backup procedure independent of Git - you should not push only for backup, but when you feel your work is fit for distribution to others.

Answer (score 1):

When working in a team, frequent pushing makes life easier for you personally, because the one who pushes last needs to solve the merge conflict. Others who push less frequently can make their life easier in this regard by pulling more often so that conflicts are detected before their repository diverges too far.

The drawback of pushing frequently is that after you pushed a commit, you can't reorder or squash your commits using rebase and you can't ammend them anymore. This might be a personal thing, but when I have a trivial change which would fit under the description of the previous commit, I rather amend the previous one instead of creating a new one. After you pushed you can't do that anymore. So when you push frequently, you will end up with a lot more trivial commits which inflate the git log unnecessary.